# Is the Auto Slapper skill damage based off of my slap level?

Tags: best-fiends-forever

The Auto Slapper skill is the first skill you unlock with your fiends. What is the damage of this skill based on?

Does leveling the normal slap increase the damage of the Auto Slapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Auto Slaps deal damage based off of your regular slap level.

In game, if you tap on the skill name it will display this screen confirming how it works:

[image: autoslap info]